# Query filter not working, but GQL is: bug in app engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Can not reproduce this error on local devserver (1.5.0) but when we deploy code to google, it starts popping up?  Is it a bug in the current online version of GAE?

Here is the problem.  If we first do this:

```
proj = Project(created_by=users.User(email='test@sample.com'))
proj.put()
user = users.get_current_user()
print user.email()  #this prints test@sample.com (actual email not used)
```

This fetches 0 results:

```
projs = Project.all().filter('created_by', user).fetch(500)
```

But this fetches the result that should actually be fetched:

```
projs = GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Project where created_by = USER('%s')"%user.email()).fetch(500)
```

Any idea whats going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As i could see you are creating a user object and persisting that into created_by.
i.e

```
users.User(email='test@sample.com')
```

here you are creating a users.User object with email 'test@sample.com'. You are persisting the same into Projects' created_by. Where as you are comparing that with `users.get_current_user()` which gets the current logged in user object.That's why it's not fetching any object. Whereas in gql you are again creating a User object with the passed email which obviously will match the persisted user object in project.

i would say you should do something like this

```
proj = Project()
proj.created_by  = users.get_current_user()
proj.put()
user = users.get_current_user()
Project().all().filter('created_by',user).get()
```

Comment: So can a user object that matches the users.get_current_user() be constructed?  If yes, how?

Comment: why do you want to construct one when you can always get one by calling user.get_current_user()

Comment: UserA wants to add UserB to a project in a way that if UserB logs on, she can fetch the project with a query using the user from user.get_current_user()

Comment: @Yasser As Nick johnson suggested creating a User object from email is a bad idea, i would say you should persist user=get_current_user().user_id() and query for the same.

Answer (score 3):

This occurs because the `User` object you created has a matching email address, but not a matching user ID (since it doesn't have one), and thus doesn't show up as a match in query results. There are several problems with your current approach:

- Email addresses aren't guaranteed to remain the same - a user can change their email address
- Email addresses aren't guaranteed to be unique - someone could claim an address another user has vacated
- Querying on user properties matches on properties other than the email address

In general, querying on the user property is dangerous and likely to lead to issues like this. I'd recommend putting the user's user_id property in a string, and querying on that, instead.

Comment: From GAE docs: "If the email address is associated with a Google account, user_id returns the unique permanent ID of the user, a str. This ID is always the same for the user regardless of whether the user changes her email address.
If the email address is not associated with a Google account, user_id returns None."  So with federated login, what should we use in queries?

Answer (score 0):

The filter syntax is incorrect. You need to show the operator (in this case, '=').

```
projs = Project.all().filter('created_by =', user).fetch(500)
```

Comment: But that doesn't explain why it succeeds on the dev server, unless that server is more forgiving with syntax.

Comment: Actually that is incorrect.  From the GAE filter documentation: 'If the operator is omitted from the string (the argument is just the property name), the filter uses the = operator.'  BTW doesnt work even with the equality filter.